# Save Values from a DHT11 Sensor to a CSV file

Tags: python

I am working with a RBPI4B and have installed the dht11 sensor. The code that I am using is working fine with the dht library and get the results. I need to save the output values to a csv under a /temp folder. Can you please help me? I would like to save it to a data.csv file, with: date, time, tempc, tempf, humidty (columns)

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import dht11
import time
import datetime

# initialize GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.cleanup()

# read data using pin 14
instance = dht11.DHT11(pin=17)

while True:
        result = instance.read()
        if result.is_valid():
                print("Last valid input: " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
                print("Temperature: %d C" % result.temperature)
                print("Temperature: %d F" % ((result.temperature * 9/5)+32))
                print("Humidity: %d %%" % result.humidity)
time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use python's [file writer](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) to read and write to files

```
with open('data.csv','w') as file:

    while True:
            result = instance.read()
            if result.is_valid():
                file.write("{:s},{:d},{:f},{:d}\n".format(
                    str(datetime.datetime.now()),
                    result.temperature,
                    ((result.temperature * 9/5)+32),
                    result.humidity
                ))
```

Comment: Thank you DollarAkshay, were do I set the lines? above or below the timesleep?

Comment: @OliverCasasola add the `file.write(...)` below the if condition